H2 start chrome.exe with profile switch from shell script executing in git-bash? (windows)
I want to start chrome.exe from a shell (bash) script, running git-bash, with a certain chrome profile (and ofc a URL).
I have tried executing chrome.exe from its location. I tried using start, but no success...
echo ----------------------------------------

function openSomeUrl() {
        local URL="https://github.com/chipbite/"
    # some url
    local BROWSER='/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'

    echo "$BROWSER" "$URL"

    # so for some URLs, I want a private profile, for others my work profile
    # I have without success tried e g 
    # (1) adding the switches separately (ie $BROWSER $SWITCHES $URL), 
    # (2) to the BROWSER variable/command and 
    # (3) as a part of/prefix to the $URL variable, as below, here:

    if ( echo $URL | grep -q chipbite ); then
      URL="--profile-directory='Profile 1' $URL" 
    else
      # URL="--profile-directory='Default' $URL"  
      echo default
    fi
 
    echo "$BROWSER" $URL # 1 - without quotes
    # "$BROWSER" $URL  
            # --> /c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe --profile-directory='Profile 1' https://github.com/chipbite/
            # opens in default profile, tries url-> 1' -- as in the end of 'Profile 1'

    echo "$BROWSER" "$URL" # 2 - with quotes. prints exactly same as 1, but that is since they are not escaped.
    "$BROWSER" $URL
}

openSomeUrl

echo ----------------------------------------

It works without the profile switch. So the issue I seem to have is to get it working with commandline switches.
I have tried a gazillion ways of escaping and so on, but I am grasping for straws in the dark, it feels like.
(Probable workaround: I think if I add chrome.exe to the PATH, it might work. But I dislike that, can't add every executable location to the path.)

Related posts I have looked at include:

how to open google chrome in git bash terminal (Windows 10)

An answer here proposed the workaround to add chrome.exe to the path.


Launch Chrome with command line switches has no effect

Similar issue.


https://superuser.com/questions/377186/how-do-i-start-chrome-using-a-specified-user-profile



Thanks for reading my question!

"$BROWSER" "$URL" expands and runs as
"/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe" "--profile-directory='Profile 1' https://github.com/chipbite/"

I.e. it attempts to run Chrome with a single command line argument "--profile-directory='Profile 1' https://github.com/chipbite/".
Remove quotation marks around $URL.

Thanks alot for taking the time to help me out!
I tried removing the quotation marks, but it seems to misinterpret the parameters and the result is that chrome opens two tabs, one with the url (last parameter) and one with: 1' as url. So one issue here seems to be how to be able to provide the profile-directory parameter with a name of the profile folder that includes a space, which they all do.
